# What does :: (double colon) mean in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, syntax, operators

What does `::` mean in Ruby? E.g. `Foo::Bar`.

Answer (score 22):

[From the Pickaxe](http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/language.html#invokingamethod):

> When a receiver is explicitly specified in a method invocation, it may be separated from the method name using either a period (`.`) or two colons (`::`). The only difference between these two forms occurs if the method name starts with an uppercase letter. In this case, Ruby will assume that a `receiver::Thing` method call is actually an attempt to access a constant called `Thing` in the receiver unless the method invocation has a parameter list between parentheses.

Answer (score 9):

It's called a scope resolution operator.  Basically a fancy way of referencing a class within a namespace.  ActiveRecord is the namespace and Base is the class.

Comment: What's fancy about it? It's the normal way to do this.

Comment: @Chuck that's true.  I'm speaking from my VB/C# prospective.

Answer (score 3):

It accesses constants in a given class or module. E.g. `ActiveRecord::Base` is the constant `Base` defined in the module `ActiveRecord`.