# What does ::MyClass Ruby scope operator do?

Tags: ruby

What does the `::MyClass/MyModule` scope operator do in Ruby, what is its purpose?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This explicitly refers to the MyClass in the global scope.  If there is a MyClass in the global scope, but also a MyClass inside of SomeModule, referring to MyClass from inside of SomeModule will refer to MyClass inside of the module, not the global MyClass.  Saying ::MyClass explicitly refers to the MyClass in the global scope.

```
class MyClass
  def self.something
    puts "Global MyClass"
  end
end

module SomeModule
  class MyClass
    def self.something
      puts "SomeModule::MyClass"
    end
  end

  print "From the module: "
  MyClass.something

  print "Explicitly using global scope: "
  ::MyClass.something
end

print "From the global scope: "
MyClass.something

print "Explicitly using module scope: "
SomeModule::MyClass.something
```

Answer (score 3):

"global scope" just means the constant is defined on the `Object` class. So `::SomeModule` is shorthand for `Object::SomeModule`