# Ruby 2.2+, using kind_of?(Class) inside a module extending Hash core class does not work

Tags: ruby, module, monkeypatching

This works as expected:

```
h = { a: "alpha" }
h.kind_of?(Hash) # => true
```

However, when I try to extend a core Ruby class with a module, it doesn't seem to work:

```
module CoreExtensions
  module Hash
    module Keys
      def my_custom_method
        self.each do |k, v|
          self.kind_of?(Hash) # => false
        end
      end
    end
  end
end

Hash.include CoreExtensions::Hash::Keys

h = { a: "alpha" }
h.my_custom_method
```

Note that this is a contrived example of code that demonstrates my problem.

Is there something different about using `object.kind_of?(Class)` inside a module like this?  My assumption is that using `self` is referencing the module somehow and not the actual `Hash` class, but `self.class # => Hash` so it "quacks" like a Hash class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Hash` in `self.kind_of?(Hash)` refers to `CoreExtensions::Hash`. Try `p Hash` if you want to see for yourself.

Your code can be fixed by referring to the global `Hash` class instead: `self.kind_of?(::Hash)`. [See this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3597096/what-does-myclass-ruby-scope-operator-do) if you're not familiar with how `::` is used here.

Comment: Ha! It's the little things that get you...I'm familiar with the :: but didn't even think about it here. Much appreciated.