# Ruby syntax question

Tags: ruby, syntax

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Double colons rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4819312/double-colons-rails)
>   [What does :: do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4829189/what-does-do)

I was reading a manual on Rails and came across this snippet:

```
match 'rocketeer.js' => ::TestRoutingMapper::RocketeerApp
```

I'd never seen the `::` syntax at the head of a class name before. I'm wondering what is the significance of writing it this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See my answer to [What does :: do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4829189/what-does-do/4829239#4829239)