# Use an object from outside your modules scope

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have code like this.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
end

module Foo
  class User
  end
end

module Foo
  class DoesSomethingWithActiveRecordUser
    def initialize user_id
      User.find(user_id)
    end
  end
end
```

If I call `Foo::DoesSomethingWithActiveRecordUser.new(1)` I get an error message that says something like `undefined method 'find' for Foo::User`.

How do I call the ActiveRecord User from within `Foo`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Like this:

```
::User.find(user_id)
```

Comment: I know I tried that and it didn't work.  But now it seems to.  Can you point to some documentation on why/what this does?

Comment: By prepending :: you are accessing the top name-space. Otherwise, ruby will look in your current module.

Comment: I can't find any documentation specifically on this, but it's pretty simple as @ylan-s pointed out. It's just anchoring the reference to the root in the class/module namespace.

Comment: @mwoods79 You can see few questions about that. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4829189/what-does-do http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4819312/double-colons-rails