# Simple ruby syntax question

Tags: ruby, class, syntax

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is Ruby's double-colon (::) all about?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3009477/what-is-rubys-double-colon-all-about)

Can you explain me, what two dots `::` in ruby means?

Explain me on this example:

```
AWS::S3::Bucket.find(BUCKET).objects
```

What is here ASW, what S3, and what is Bucket (I mean, classes, packets, objects,...)

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3009477/what-is-rubys-double-colon-all-about.

Comment: "Simple ruby ... question" is not a very helpful title. 1) Don't describe how difficult the question is in the title. 2) Everything in Stack Overflow is a question, so saying that it's a question is redundant. So all the title tells us is that it's about Ruby syntax.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the exact code that you are using under the hood:

https://github.com/marcel/aws-s3/blob/master/lib/aws/s3/bucket.rb

As you can see, there are nested modules/classes:

```
module AWS
  module S3
     class Bucket < Base
     end
  end
end
```

So:

- AWS is a module.
- S3 is a module.
- Bucket is a class.

The class Bucket is nested inside the module S3 which is nested inside the module AWS.

A Module is basically a bundle of methods/constants, but they differ from classes in the sense where they can't have instances.  You use that a lot in order to refactor your code and to better design it. More information on Modules [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_modules.htm).

The :: is used to refer to the nested modules/classes. It's a kind of resolution operator, that helps you reach your nested modules/classes/constants by knowing their paths.

Answer (score 3):

It's a [ruby module](http://www.rubyfleebie.com/an-introduction-to-modules-part-1/). A module is a container of classes, and it's used to separate the namespace, it's similar (in a way) to java packages.