# What is significant about the "::" notation?

Tags: ruby

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is Ruby's double-colon (::) all about?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3009477/what-is-rubys-double-colon-all-about)

What is the "`::`" telling me in this code example?  I'm working thru the ruby koans and don't fully understand this code chuck.

```
class ::Integer
  def even?
    (self % 2) == 0
  end
end
```

Comment: not a duplicate of the referenced question. This is more specifically about `::` as a *root-level* namespace identifier, not as a generic scope resolution operator

Comment: Looks like there much more of those, who are able to vote to close a question, that those, who are really understand it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's going to the root namespace.

Comment: If that's true is there a long form I could use instead?  I assume there is nothing ahead of the "::" because that is shorthand for <Something>::Integer?

Comment: no, it's the opposite; to say that you're looking for `Integer` in the *top* namespace, *without* anything in front of it. Otherwise, inside of a module `Foo`, a reference to `Integer` would point to `Foo::Integer` if it existed

Answer (score -1):

It's the namespace resolution operator.

This S/O question has more detail:

[What is Ruby's double-colon `::`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3009477/what-is-rubys-double-colon-all-about)