# Rails migration not working on heroku, Model class reported as uninitialized constant

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, migration

I'm trying to run a migration on heroku and I can't seem to find the problem why my model class is not recognized.

This is my migration:

```
class AddTestToGoals < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :goals, :test, :integer, default: 0, null: false
    Goal.reset_column_information
    Goal.all.each { |g| g.update_attribute :test, Goal::PASS }
  end
end
```

Running it using

```
heroku run rake db:migrate
```

and I get this error

```
uninitialized constant AddTestToGoals::Goal
```

Anyone knows what the problem is?

EDIT: miss typed before, it's the model which is not recognized, not the constant in it.

HALF WORKAROUND:

Using this (which I found here: http://visibletrap.blogspot.co.il/2011/10/heroku-access-railss-model-in-migration.html)

```
class AddTestToGoals < ActiveRecord::Migration
  class Goal < ActiveRecord::Base; end
  def change
     add_column :goals, :test, :integer, default: 0, null: false
     Goal.reset_column_information
     Goal.all.each { |g| g.update_attribute :test, Goal::PASS }
  end
end
```

heroku doesn't complain about not knowing what Goal is which solves half of the problem.
but then, Goal::PASS is not recognized.

Comment: Does the migration fail?

Comment: Yes, it does. Can't figure out this error.

Comment: It seems to be a reference issue. See my answer below and refer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3009477/what-is-rubys-double-colon-all-about

Comment: Half Workaround has error in later rails - "class definition in method body"

Answer (score 10):

Old question, but I recently experienced something like it which was due to autoloading being disabled by setting

```
config.threadsafe!
```

in my environments/staging.rb file.
It can be fixed by replacing it with the following

```
config.threadsafe! unless $rails_rake_task
```

This should be OK as there is no need for rake tasks to be threadsafe.

Comment: thank u a lot =) recently switched to multithreading in production and somehow didn't connect the issue with it.

Comment: Yeah, this caught me out too. Cheers.

Comment: Really, this saved a lot of time :)

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

Change all the references to Goal to be prefixed with `::`.

```
::Goal.reset_column_information
::Goal.all.each { |g| g.update_attribute :test, ::Goal::PASS }
```

Comment: doesn't help. the error is now: "uninitialized constant UserGoal".

Comment: Why are you declaring the Goal class inside the ActiveRecord::Migration?

Comment: In the half workaround? because I read somewhere that it should help. I have no idea why.

Comment: Trying this to make it possible to update the attributes of a related-model while doing the migration.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I am missing something, all workarounds above have been blocked in later rails-versions.  But one can still take control of their project/work from artificially-imposed constraints, by doing something like:

```
execute("INSERT INTO table_name (col_name) VALUES (your_values_here))")
```