# Calling a Rails constant in a module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I declared a module `MigrationProcedures` in app/concerns, which I would like to use to execute some unsupported ActiveRecord SQL statements.

Inside this module, I need to call the constant

`[RAILS_ENV]['database']`

but as it stands right now, rails tells me that there is an uninitialized constant `RAILS_ENV` in the method.

I should not that this is being used under

```
def self.included(base)
...
end
```

I tried to use `AppName::RAILS_ENV` but that tells me that `MigrationProcedures::AppName` dosen't exist. How can I call this constant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get at the Rails environment a couple of ways:

```
c = ::Rails.application.config
my_env = ::ENV
```

In the first case `c.database_configuration[Rails.env]["database"]` gives you what you want.

The `::SOME_MODULE` syntax gets you out of your current namespace and into a new one.  Without a module name, it takes you to the top of your Ruby environment.

[This Stack Overflow discussion is very illuminating.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3009477/what-is-rubys-double-colon-all-about)