# What does a double colon do inside a module?

Tags: ruby, module

I'm looking at the following code:

```
module Tag

  def sync_taggings_counter
    ::Tag.find_each do |t|
       # block here
    end
  end
end
```

and I'm confused by `::Tag` inside the Tag module.

I know the double colon is used to name-space classes and modules within classes/modules.  But I've never seen it used like the above.  What does it mean exactly?

Comment: I wasn't right. Take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3009477/what-is-rubys-double-colon-all-about

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's a scope modifier. Prefixing your constant (`Tag`) with a double colon ensures that you're looking in the root/global namespace instead of within your current module.

E.g.

```
module Foo
  class Bar
    def self.greet
      "Hello from the Foo::Bar class"
    end
  end

  class Baz
    def self.scope_test
      Bar.greet # Resolves to the Bar class within the Foo module.
      ::Bar.greet # Resolves to the global Bar class.
    end
  end
end

class Bar
  def self.greet
    "Hello from the Bar class"
  end
end
```

The prepending is usually not neccessary as Ruby automatically looks in the global namespace, if it fails to find the referenced constant in the local module. So if no `Bar` existed in the Foo module, then `Bar.greet` and `::Bar.greet` would do the exact same thing.