# My class name conflicting with Ruby's

Tags: ruby, class, conflict

I have a class in my module that is called "Date". But when i want to utilize the Date class packaged with ruby, it uses my Date class instead.

```
module Mymod
  class ClassA
    class Date < Mymod::ClassA
      require 'date'

      def initialize
        today = Date.today # get today's date from Ruby's Date class
        puts "Today's date is #{today.to_s}"
      end
    end
  end
end

Mymod::ClassA::Date.new
```

The ouput from running this is

```
test.rb:7:in `initialize': undefined method `today' for Mymod::ClassA::Date:Class (NoMethodError)
```

Is there any way I can reference ruby's Date class from within my own class also called "Date"?

Comment: `::Date` should help.

Comment: `::Date` is the answer, but I'd advise against giving your class the same name as a common system class - it will be harder for other people to make sense of your code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
def initialize
        today = ::Date.today # get today's date from Ruby's Date class
        puts "Today's date is #{today.to_s}"
      end
```

[What is double colon in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3009477/what-is-rubys-double-colon-all-about)

Answer (score 5):

In your code `Date` implicitly looks for the `Date` class declaration from *within* the `Date < Mymod::ClassA` class scope – this `Date` declaration does not include the method `today`.

In order to reference Ruby's core `Date` class, you'll want to specify that you're looking in the root scope. Do this by prefixing the `Date` with the [`::` scope resolution operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_resolution_operator#Ruby):

```
today = ::Date.today # Resolves to `Date` class in the root scope
```

**However**, in truth, you should avoid naming conflicts/collisions when it comes to Ruby core classes. They're named with convention in mind, and it's typically less confusing/more descriptive to name custom classes something *other* than the same name as a core class.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with others that you should change the name of your class, but you could do this:

```
module Mymod
  require 'date'
  RubyDate = Date
  Date = nil      
  class ClassA
    class Date < Mymod::ClassA
      def initialize
        today = RubyDate.today # get today's date from Ruby's Date class
        puts "Today's date is #{today.to_s}"
      end
    end
  end
end

Mymod::ClassA::Date.new # => Today's date is 2014-01-05
```