# Understanding ruby libraries

Tags: ruby

I'm testing this small Ruby program:

```
require 'net/http'
url = URI.parse('http://www.rubyinside.com/')
response = Net::HTTP.start(url.host, url.port) do |http|
   http.get(url.path)
end
content = response.body
```

And I don't understand why `URI.parse` doesn't have the prefix `Net::` and `Net::HTTP.start` have it.

**What does `Net::` means?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Net` is a module (ie. a namespace) and `HTTP` is a class, so by `Net::HTTP` you are accessing the `HTTP` class that is namespaced under the `Net` module.

`::` is the namespace resolution operator, For more info see [What is Ruby's double-colon (::) all about?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3009477/what-is-rubys-double-colon-all-about).

As others have pointed, [`Net::HTTP`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html) is designed to work closely with [`URI`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html) which is *another* module (you could use it alone without `net/http` by doing a `require 'uri'`).

Thus when you require `net/http` it also requires `uri`, and that's the reason you can access it using `URI` in your code.

Answer (score 0):

> why URI.parse doesn't have the prefix Net::

[Simple Examples](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html#class-Net%3a%3aHTTP-label-Simple+Examples) says that - **when you would do `require 'net/http'`, then This will also `require ‘uri’` so you don’t need to require it separately.** [URI::parse](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html#method-c-parse) is a method of the [`URI`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html) module. Remember `URI` and `Net` are two different module.

[`Net`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/net/ftp/rdoc/Net.html) is a module. Under `Net` module [`HTTP`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html) class has been defined.

`::` is the namespace/scope resolution operator. So to access the `HTTP` class inside the module `Net`,we need to use `Net::HTTP`.[`#start`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html#method-i-start) is a method of the class `Net::HTTP`, that's why the call like `Net::HTTP.start`.

Answer (score 0):

1) **Net::** means the code is found in a module Net(namespace of ruby). It can be found in a folder net.
2) URI.parse doesn't have the prefix Net because it does not belong to Net::