# configure init data for Gabba in initializer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm configuring this gem: https://github.com/hybridgroup/gabba/ in my application.

I would like to store the initialization data inside an initializer in `config/initializers/gabba.rb` so that I can better protect and manage this information.

I've created the file, `config/initializers/gabba.rb`:

```
module Gabba
  class Gabba
    TRACKING_CODE = "UA-00000000-0"
    DOMAIN_NAME = "mydomain.com"
  end
end
```

and restarted my server, but I don't know how to reference to these new variables in my controller.

```
Gabba::Gabba.new(Gabba::Gabba.TRACKING_CODE, Gabba:Gabba.DOMAIN_NAME).page_view("something", "track/me")
```

doesn't seem to work.

any clue?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Gabba::Gabba.new(Gabba::Gabba::TRACKING_CODE, Gabba:Gabba::DOMAIN_NAME).page_view("something", "track/me")
```

In Ruby, you access constants defined with in a **module** or a **class** with `::`, which is a namespace resolution operator.

So, in your case. You can access `TRACKING_CODE` and `DOMAIN_NAME` like this:

```
Gabba::Gabba::TRACKING_CODE #=> "UA-00000000-0"
Gabba::Gabba::DOMAIN_NAME #=> "mydomain.com"
```

For more explanation on `::`, [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3009477/what-is-rubys-double-colon-all-about).