# ruby difference between class ClassName and class ::ClassName

Tags: ruby

what's the difference between `class ClassName` and `class ::ClassName` in ruby?

```
class ClassName
end
```

vs

```
class ::ClassName
end
```

Comment: The [second answer to that question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5318496/1318694) explains the root name space

Answer (score 4):

Your two examples would make difference if the classes were **defined inside a ruby module**, so:

```
module Foo
  class ClassName
  end 
end
```

would define a new class inside the `Foo` module. This could be accessed like `Foo::ClassName`.

On the other hand, this:

```
module Foo
  class ::ClassName
  end 
end
```

would define (or monkey-patch) the class `ClassName` in the **root namespace**.

Answer (score 1):

`::Class` says 'look for Class in top level namespace'. The difference shows when in context of a module.

```
module A
  def foo
    X.new
  end
end

A.foo # => A::X.new

module B
  def foo
    ::X.new
  end
end

B.foo # => X.new
```