# ruby on rails, colon at back or front of variables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, variables, constants

What I understand so far is that **:variable** in ruby, is to say that this variable will not be able to change, which is similar to constant in other language. Am I correct??

Then my confusion is, sometimes I see the colon in front of variable, like this

```rb
Rails.application.config.session_store :cookie_store, 
      key: '_blog_session'
  <%= link_to "Delete", article, confirm: "Are you sure?", 
      method: :delete %>
```

Both **key:** and **method:** has colon in front.What does that this represent?

Furthermore

```rb
Blog::Application.routes.draw.do
  root :to => "articles#index"
end
```

There are double colons in between variables?

I am guessing that Blog: is one variable, and :Application is constant, which I doubt it is. Please enlighten me?

Comment: This is neither a variable, nor a constant. It's literal syntax to Ruby [Symbol](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Symbol.html). `Blog::Application` syntax isn't related to symbols, it's about resolving [namespaces](http://ruby-doc.com/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/tut_modules.html).

Comment: Just to be clear, do you mean Blog is a namespace? or Application is a namespace? what about colon in front of, like method: or key:

Comment: Blog is namespace. Look at the link I provided. Syntax like `{method: 'delete'}` etc. is a hash syntax, equivalent to `{:method => 'delete'}`.

Comment: I see. I will check your link, thanks. I should give you the points then. :)

Answer (score 63, accepted):

> What i have understand so far is that `:variable` in ruby, is to say that this variable will not be able to change, which is similar to constant in other language.

I'm not sure if I understand that statement. In Ruby, **constants** start with an uppercase letter:

```
Foo = 1
```

Reassignment generates a warning:

```
Foo = 1
Foo = 2 #=> warning: already initialized constant Foo
```

**Variables** start with a lowercase letter and reassignment doesn't cause a warning (they are supposed to change):

```
foo = 1
foo = 2 # no warning
```

**Symbols** start with a colon:

```
:a_symbol
:Uppercase_symbol
:"i'm a symbol, too"
```

They often represent static values, e.g. `:get` and `:post`. Symbols are memory efficient, because they are created only once - the same symbol literal always returns the same object. Checking if two symbols are equal is a cheap operation.

> Both `key:` and `method:` (...) What does that this represent?

This is an alternate syntax for hashes. You can type it in IRB to see the result:

```
{ foo: 1, bar: 2 }
#=> {:foo=>1, :bar=>2}
```

> There are double colons inbetween variables? now I am guessing that `Blog:` is one variable, and `:Application` is constant.

No, `Blog` and `Application` are both constants and `::` is the scope resolution operator. It can be used to access nested constants, e.g.:

```
module Foo
  class Bar
    BAZ = 123
  end
end

Foo::Bar::BAZ #=> 123
```

Comment: @Stefan one more confusion `params  = { }` 
params[mehtods:] = :delete  syntax error, unexpected '] ` but if params[:mehtods] = :delete
now it is fine why ?

Comment: @VinayGupta the alternate syntax only works for key-value *pairs*, e.g. `{ method: :delete }`. Otherwise, the colon comes always first.

Comment: Very concise. Like this answer

Answer (score 15):

```
Rails.application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_blog_session'
```

`session_store` is a method that takes two "Arguments":

- `:cookie_store` is a [Symbol](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Symbol.html)
- `key: '_blog_session'` is actually a short way of writing a [Hash](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html).

(could also be `session_store :cookie_store, { key: '_blog_session' }`)

Similarly for `link_to "Delete", article, confirm: "Are you sure?", method: :delete`

- `"Delete"` is a string
- `article` a variable
- `{ confirm: '...', method: :delete }` hash where `confirm:`, `method:` and `:delete` are Symbols again.

While `Blog::Application` [:: is basically a namespace resolution operator.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3009477/what-is-rubys-double-colon-all-about) A way for you to address the Application class in the `Blog` module.

Hope this helps. Have a look at the documentation I referenced, it is explained rather nicely.

Comment: `confirm: "Are you sure?", method: :delete` is *one* hash, not two

Answer (score 1):

:presence => true

presence: true

In the bottom example, the colon is saying, “Hey, I am pointing from presence to true.