# superclass mismatch for class Event (TypeError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, clockwork

I have an event model in my rails app:

```
    class Event < ApplicationRecord   
      ... 
    end
```

I am running a clockwork process on clock dyno which has

```
require_relative 'boot'
require_relative 'environment'
require 'clockwork'
module Clockwork
  every(10.seconds, 'xyz') do
      Resque.enqueue(.......)
    end
  every(2.seconds, '.....') do
      Resque.enqueue(.......)
  end
end
```

This clock.rb file has a resque job that it calls at a given cadence. It works fine when I run the clockwork and queue in separate terminals locally but when I deploy it on heroku it fails because of me trying to require the environment.rb file in my clock.rb (I tried to deploy on heroku without requiring the environment but it raises other issues in Clockwork module). The part that I do not understand is that why is it just failing for event.rb? And if it does fail on heroku, it should have failed locally too.

The error looks like:

```
2017-06-02T06:25:24.578369+00:00 app[clock.1]: /app/app/models/event.rb:1:in `<top (required)>': superclass mismatch for class Event (TypeError)
2017-06-02T06:25:24.578383+00:00 app[clock.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
2017-06-02T06:25:24.578384+00:00 app[clock.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `block in require'
2017-06-02T06:25:24.578385+00:00 app[clock.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in `load_dependency'
2017-06-02T06:25:24.578385+00:00 app[clock.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
2017-06-02T06:25:24.578389+00:00 app[clock.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:380:in `block in require_or_load'
2017-06-02T06:25:24.578389+00:00 app[clock.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:37:in `block in load_interlock'
2017-06-02T06:25:24.578390+00:00 app[clock.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:12:in `block in loading'
2017-06-02T06:25:24.578391+00:00 app[clock.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.3/lib/active_support/concurrency/share_lock.rb:150:in `exclusive'
2017-06-02T06:25:24.578392+00:00 app[clock.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:11:in `loading'
2017-06-02T06:25:24.578393+00:00 app[clock.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:37:in `load_interlock'
2017-06-02T06:25:24.578393+00:00 app[clock.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:358:in `require_or_load'
2017-06-02T06:25:24.578397+00:00 app[clock.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:336:in `depend_on'
2017-06-02T06:25:24.578398+00:00 app[clock.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:252:in `require_dependency'
2017-06-02T06:25:24.578399+00:00 app[clock.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:476:in `block (2 levels) in eager_load!'
2017-06-02T06:25:24.578400+00:00 app[clock.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:475:in `each'
2017-06-02T06:25:24.578400+00:00 app[clock.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:475:in `block in eager_load!'
2017-06-02T06:25:24.578401+00:00 app[clock.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:473:in `each'
2017-06-02T06:25:24.578402+00:00 app[clock.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:473:in `eager_load!'
2017-06-02T06:25:24.578402+00:00 app[clock.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:354:in `eager_load!'
2017-06-02T06:25:24.578403+00:00 app[clock.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.3/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:59:in `each'
2017-06-02T06:25:24.578404+00:00 app[clock.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.3/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:59:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
2017-06-02T06:25:24.578404+00:00 app[clock.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
2017-06-02T06:25:24.578405+00:00 app[clock.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
2017-06-02T06:25:24.578405+00:00 app[clock.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
2017-06-02T06:25:24.578406+00:00 app[clock.1]:  from /app/vendor/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:228:in `block in tsort_each'
2017-06-02T06:25:24.578407+00:00 app[clock.1]:  from /app/vendor/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
2017-06-02T06:25:24.578407+00:00 app[clock.1]:  from /app/vendor/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:431:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
2017-06-02T06:25:24.578408+00:00 app[clock.1]:  from /app/vendor/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:349:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
2017-06-02T06:25:24.578410+00:00 app[clock.1]:  from /app/vendor/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each'
2017-06-02T06:25:24.578411+00:00 app[clock.1]:  from /app/vendor/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:347:in `call'
2017-06-02T06:25:24.578411+00:00 app[clock.1]:  from /app/vendor/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
2017-06-02T06:25:24.578412+00:00 app[clock.1]:  from /app/vendor/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:226:in `tsort_each'
2017-06-02T06:25:24.578413+00:00 app[clock.1]:  from /app/vendor/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
2017-06-02T06:25:24.578414+00:00 app[clock.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
2017-06-02T06:25:24.578414+00:00 app[clock.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.3/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in `initialize!'
2017-06-02T06:25:24.578416+00:00 app[clock.1]:  from /app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
2017-06-02T06:25:24.578417+00:00 app[clock.1]:  from /app/config/clock.rb:2:in `require_relative'
2017-06-02T06:25:24.578417+00:00 app[clock.1]:  from /app/config/clock.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
2017-06-02T06:25:24.578420+00:00 app[clock.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/clockwork-0.2.4/bin/clockwork:13:in `require'
2017-06-02T06:25:24.578421+00:00 app[clock.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/clockwork-0.2.4/bin/clockwork:13:in `<top (required)>'
2017-06-02T06:25:24.578421+00:00 app[clock.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/bin/clockwork:17:in `load'
2017-06-02T06:25:24.578422+00:00 app[clock.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/bin/clockwork:17:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Can you try sticking a debug line in there, to see if/where `Event` has been defined already? It appears you have conflicting definitions.

Comment: can you show your clock.rb file please?

Comment: The error means that class `Event` is defined somewhere else. Perhaps by some gem you are using?

Comment: I understand that the error means I have a same class name somewhere else in the project but I couldn't find it anywhere in the project. Maybe, a gem might have the same class name, but how can I find if there's any gem that has a class with the same name? (I am relatively new to Rails :))

Comment: I have updated the original post with clock.rb

Comment: So, I see that Clockwork gem has a Event class in there. Is there a possible solution to this problem? Considering that event.rb can not be removed.

Comment: You have a conflict of class names. You are trying to use your Event class in the Clockwork module which already defines an Event class. Try using **::Event** to reference your Event class, See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3009477/what-is-rubys-double-colon) for details of the :: syntax.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the exact same error and circumstances -- Ruby, Rails, Clockwork.  It only happens in production.  My solution was to simply rename my event class to external_event and once I did that then everything just worked.  At best this is a crappy solution but I think it is because of the require / include structure that clockwork relies on which effectively bring its internal namespace into the app itself.