# What is the correct way to put this piece of code in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I need to know the correct way to type this:
`environment: :sandbox` or `environment::sandbox`?

Edit: I saw your comments, maybe if I type in the code that I used, I will get a better answer?

```rb
require_relative 'lib/gocardless_pro'

    @client = GoCardlessPro::Client.new(
        access_token: ENV['GOCARDLESS_TOKEN'],
        # environment: :sandbox or environment::sandbox?
    )
```

Comment: Those mean two different things. We'd need to know the context.

Comment: @Schwern: actually, they mean four to five different things. The first one alone means three to four. (Depending on how you count.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    @client = GoCardlessPro::Client.new(
        access_token: ENV['GOCARDLESS_TOKEN'],
        # environment: :sandbox or environment::sandbox?
    )
```

In this context you're passing in [keyword arguments](https://www.rubyguides.com/2018/06/rubys-method-arguments/) to a method. This is, basically, a Hash where the key is a [Symbol](https://ruby-doc.org/core/doc/syntax/literals_rdoc.html#label-Symbols) and the value is whatever you like. So it would be `environment: :sandbox`.

```
    @client = GoCardlessPro::Client.new(
        access_token: ENV['GOCARDLESS_TOKEN'],
        environment: :sandbox
    )
```

That passes the argument `:environment` with the value `:sandbox`.

`:access_token`, `:environment`, and `:sandbox` are Symbols, sort of read-only strings that also use less memory.

`environment: :sandbox` is shorthand for the more conventional syntax `:key => :value`. You can replace `:key =>` with simply `key:`.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely it is `environment: :sandbox`, where you are defining a hash key `environment` to hold the value `:sandbox`, which is a [symbolized string](https://medium.com/@pk60905/string-and-symbol-in-ruby-cb0bf0d4dd2c).

Your confusion probably comes from the fact that `Module::Class` is valid syntax, but your example in lowercase is not valid syntax, and I am guessing from the context of your question you are not attempting to use a [namespace separator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3009477/3784008).

Answer (score 1):

Both are correct, but only the second one is a generally valid expression. The first one is only valid in three limited contexts where it means three to four different things.

The first one is an alternative way of writing the *message send operator*.

The second one can mean:

- In a *`Hash` literal*: a *key-value pair* with key `:environment` and value `:sandbox`.
- In a *parameter list*: an *optional keyword parameter* `environment` with *default argument* `:sandbox`.
- In an *argument list*: a *keyword argument* `environment` with value `:sandbox`, or

  - at the *very end* of an argument list: a key-value pair with key `:environment` and value `:sandbox` that is part of a `Hash` value bound to the last *positional argument*.

However, since you actually have neither a `Hash` literal nor a parameter list nor an argument list in your code, it is simply a `SyntaxError`.