# How to generate controller inside namespace in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have namespace `admin` in controller, and I want to generate a controller inside of the `admin` folder. How can i do it with a Rails command?

Answer (score 342, accepted):

Try `rails g controller admin/users` if you want a `users` controller inside of the `admin` namespace. Of course, exchange `users` with whatever controller name that you'd like.

Answer (score 71):

Use this command..

`rails generate controller namespace_name/controller_name`

Answer (score 20):

If you want to gen it:

```
rails generate controller namespace_name/controller_name
```

And If you want to rollback this step using:

```
rails destroy controller namespace_name/controller_name
```

Answer (score 7):

In your case it will be

```
$ rails g controller admin/controller_name
```

If we have an app structure like

- ---controllers
- --api
- -v1

and want to generate controller, do:

```
$ rails g controller api/v1/controller_name
```

In general

```
$ rails g controller namespace_1/namespace_2/...../controller_name
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also use the scope resolution operator to generate controllers within a namespace

```
rails g controller Admin::YourControllerName
```

or to generate controllers within nested namespaces

```
rails g controller Admin::YourNestedNamespace::YourControllerName
```

Ref: [What is Ruby's double-colon `::`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3009477/what-is-rubys-double-colon), [What does :: (double colon) mean in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2276905/what-does-double-colon-mean-in-ruby)