# What is difference between these two methods in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

What is difference between these two methods in Ruby?

```
class Mod   

      def doc(str)
          ...
      end

      def Mod::doc(aClass) 
          ...
      end
end
```

Comment: The latter looks like a class method to me. I'd write `def self.doc ...`, though

Comment: Thanx for your reply.

Comment: Note that `Mod.instance_methods(false) #=> [:doc]` (the first) and `Mod.methods(false) #=> [:doc]` (the second). It's curious that `instance_methods` is the name of the first method (which more commonly is invoked on a class), even though instance methods can only be invoked on instances of classes which `include` the module (but, as @JörgWMittag is fond of pointing out (sic), "there are no instance methods, just methods").

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Mod::doc()
```

is a class method, whereas

```
doc()
```

is an instance method. Here's an example of how to use both:

```
class Mod   
    def doc()
        puts 1
    end

    def Mod::doc() 
        puts 2
    end
end

a = Mod.new
a.doc   #=> 1
Mod.doc #=> 2
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2276905/what-does-double-colon-mean-in-ruby)'s a question that compares it with

```
self.doc()
```